# Sterling Numbers of First Kind Identity Combinatorical Proof

Tags: combinatorics

[image: Square brackets are sterling brackets S(n,k) is the number of ways to permute n people around k circular tables so that there is at least one person at every table.]

How would one prove this combinatorically?

Trying to think of some other example where this looks more intuitive. note that n! is also S(n+1,1), and there's also this recursive relationship S(n+1,k)=nS(n,k)+S(n,k-1), not sure if that really helps. Also note that sterling numbers of the first kind can be alternatively generated by this generating function.[image]

Answer (score 2):

The (unsinged) Sterling number of the first kind $\left[^n _k \right]$ are defined as the number of elements of $S_n$ (the symmetric group on $n$ elements) consisting of $k$ orbits. Recall that an element of $S_n$ can be expressed as
\begin{eqnarray*}
(a_1 \cdots a_{i_1}) \cdots (k_1 \cdots k_{i_k})
\end{eqnarray*}
The number of brackets $k$ is the number of orbits. Thus we are just counting the elements of $S_n$ and grading/grouping them according to the number of orbits. So
 \begin{eqnarray*}
 \sum_{k=0}^n \left[^n _k \right] =n!
\end{eqnarray*}
$\left[^n _0 \right]=0$ is worth noting.

Comment: Hi, thank you for replying. I just have one more question to ask about this. I know that the stirling number of 1st kind is telling you the number of ways to distribute n people into k tables with 1 being the least number at a table. OOoo okay now I see that's just a cycle/orbit. This makes complete sense now, thanks!